# The rubyracer + libV8

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, gemfile

Having deployed a bunch of apps with the same gemfile;

I have now a big problems that breaks anything that i do.

The rubyracer tells me that it requires `gem 'libv8', '~> 3.11.8'` to be added in the gemfile (which was not the case before).

```
An error occured while installing therubyracer (0.11.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install therubyracer -v '0.11.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

If I remove therubyracer and libv8, I get another error, that tells me the following :

```
Could not find rake-10.0.3 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
```

If I add rake in my Gemfile, same error from passenger, nothing works

Not to mention that libv8 takes 10minutes+ to install when a bundle install is run…
I anyone has experienced such problems and solved it, thx to share

+

Some people tells to use node.js instead of therubyracer… how are those two related, as node would be outside of rails ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding this to your Gemfile:-

gem 'therubyracer','0.11.0beta5'

and then bundle install. Hope this helps.

Comment: gem "execjs", "1.4.0" and gem "therubyracer", "0.10.2" worked for me on previous projects, so i used it. That was a pain in the ass to get it all; new versions on gems depending on newer ones that would just breaks… wuz unhappy about it all.